# can someone help me with the implementation of google pay upi integration in flutter

Tags: flutter, payment, google-pay, upi, flutter-method-channel

I want to integrate google pay Upi in my flutter app. I have to connect Upi on both android and IOS application.

I have tried a lot of packages available in pub, most of them have the similar issue ,they don't return the status of transaction that we have done. Then I have tried through method channel ,but i can't
find any proper documentation related to that .so I got stuck in this problem.